# Syncing multiple users with social networks on same ios device

Tags: ios

When you develop an app for IOS device, can you set it up to sync social media accounts such as Facebook or Twitter? I'm also trying to allow different users with different social media accounts to login to the same device and have them be synced automatically to their social media accounts upon login.

I'm running into an API token issue.

Comment: Can you please be more specific about the issue you're running into? Also say which frameworks or sdks you're using please.